# Redirect bash script output in editor without saving file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that outputs a few lines and I want to have it open in an editor on my system (nano, vim, whatever) to be ready to edit. However I don't want to save it to a temporary file or variable but directly in the editor (I think I need to bring the out somehow into the editor's buffer).

I naively have tried something like this (I was thinking I could pipe the output into nano somehow):

```sh
echo "test" | nano # throws Too many errors from stdin
```

Alternatively I thought of opening the output like it's a file:

```sh
nano $(echo "test")
```

It opens only the editor but it's empty. Is this even possible or is a temp file strictly necessary?

Comment: Generally, editors are designed to edit *files*. Editing some floating disembodied text isn't a normal function, so it may not be possible in all editors.

Comment: `nano $(echo "test")` basically expands to `nano test`, i.e. editing a file called `test`.  But `nano <(echo "test")` may do what you want.  `<()` returns the filename of a named pipe that contains the output of the command.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294635/what-is-the-bash-file-contents-syntax-called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
echo 'test' | nano -
```

The `-` option tells nano to read from stdin rather than a file. This is an editor specific solution though. A more robust solution would require temporary files, which you can use `mktemp` for.

Comment: `mktemp` is the most universal solution, so this is what all other tools invoking editors use. Examples include `crontab -e`, `git commit`, and `visudo`

Answer (score 1):

You could start `vi` without a filename, and then do:

```
!!ls -l
```

or

```
!!yourScript.sh
```

---

Just for completeness, if you want to go the other way, and pass a `vi` buffer full of data to an external script/command, such as `sort` or `fmt`, you can do:

```
gg!Gsort      # Go to top of file (gg), submit entire buffer (G) to "sort"
```